# Incomplete JSON data when saving to database in google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-cloud-functions

I am now trying out how to use the Google cloud functions as part of my IOT application.

But I am having issues when I send a JSON POST to the trigger endpoint. There are times that it works perfectly and sometimes the payload hex is cut in the middle.

For example the original payloadhex would be "0011029e02ffb1ffd6ffd8ffdaffe0fff500000008" and sometimes get suddenly cut to "0011029e02ffb1" when it is being saved to the database.

How I test the endpoint would be that I would send an HTTP POST using Postman with data below.

```
{
"DevEUI_uplink": {
    "DevEUI": "BC9740FFFE10549E",
    "payload_hex": "0011029e02ffb1ffd6ffd8ffdaffe0fff500000008",
}}
```

And inside the cloud function would be the nodejs12 code:

```js
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */

const moment = require("moment");
const mysql = require("mysql");
require("dotenv").config();

exports.saveFunction = (req, res) => {
  let now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  let deveui = req.body.DevEUI_uplink.DevEUI;
  let payload = req.body.DevEUI_uplink.payload_hex;

  function convertTempData(data) {
    data = parseInt(data, 16);
    if ((data & 0x8000) > 0) {
      data = data - 0x10000;
    }
    return data;
  }

  // Slice the Request Data

  let raw_payload = payload;
  let version = parseInt(payload.slice(0, 2), 16);
  let gem1 = parseInt(payload.slice(2, 4), 16);
  let gem2 = parseInt(payload.slice(4, 6), 16);
  let battery = parseInt(payload.slice(6, 8), 16) / 2;
  let payload_id = parseInt(payload.slice(8, 10), 16);
  let tempNow = convertTempData(payload.slice(10, 14));
  let tempVar1 = convertTempData(payload.slice(14, 18));
  let tempVar2 = convertTempData(payload.slice(18, 22));
  let tempVar3 = convertTempData(payload.slice(22, 26));
  let tempVar4 = convertTempData(payload.slice(26, 30));
  let tempVar5 = convertTempData(payload.slice(30, 34));
  let tempVar6 = convertTempData(payload.slice(34, 38));
  let tempVar7 = convertTempData(payload.slice(38, 42));

  // Connection String
  const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.SERVER_HOST,
    user: process.env.SERVER_USER,
    password: process.env.SERVER_PASS,
    database: process.env.SERVER_DB,
    port: process.env.SERVER_PORT,
  });

  conn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ message: "Invalid Request", error: err.message });
    }
    var sqlcoms =
      "UPDATE sd_payload SET payload = '" +
      raw_payload +
      "' , version='" +
      version +
      "', gem1='" +
      gem1 +
      "' , gem2='" +
      gem2 +
      "' , battery='" +
      battery +
      "',payload_id='" +
      payload_id +
      "',tempNow='" +
      tempNow +
      "',tempVar1='" +
      tempVar1 +
      "',tempVar2='" +
      tempVar2 +
      "',tempVar3='" +
      tempVar3 +
      "',tempVar4='" +
      tempVar4 +
      "',tempVar5='" +
      tempVar5 +
      "',tempVar6='" +
      tempVar6 +
      "',tempVar7='" +
      tempVar7 +
      "',updated_at='" +
      now +
      "' WHERE DevEUI = '" +
      deveui +
      "'";
    conn.query(sqlcoms, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res
          .status(404)
          .json({ message: "Invalid Request", error: err.message });
      }
      return res.status(201).json(result);
    });
  });
};
```

I wanted to save the entire payload to the database for checking purposes. Would you be able to advise why the post json body is being cut midway in some inserts and some inserts would be complete?

Comment: Have you logged the payload to see that it's correct? Also, your SQL query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because you're just string concatenating the query together. Try adding this key into your JSON payload, for example: `"test": " ' WHERE 1=1;-- "` - it will overwrite all sd_payloads. Use the `?` placeholders as described in `node-mysql`'s documentation: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries

Comment: Ohh, I never thought about security with this but I guess it is a good practice to start. Thank you for the heads up. I will try this. With regards to the payload, When I log the incoming buffer the data is already chopped up so maybe its the Lora Gateway Issue... Thx for the tip though!

Comment: Hey @Metono, were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sadly not yet, I'm not really sure if there are issues during the post request data from the gateway or I am doing something wrong with the post requests going inside the google cloud function/cloudrun. When I log all requests being passed by my Lora Gateway to RequestBin or to a Laravel endpoint everything is correct. That compared to the GCP cloud function/cloudrun endpoint I see incomplete payload data. Any ideas what I can check in GCP? logging shows I am only receiving incomplete json data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first `console.log(payload)` so to verify if it's received in full by the function, or it gets chopped somewhere on the way.

Comment: When I do logging with the first incoming data, the payload is already chopped up in  nodejs endpoint but comparing with my PHP server endpoint it is always complete.